# Efficient algorithm to find 2-step neighbors for all vertices in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, numpy, graph-algorithm

I have a large directed graph in csv format (~14GB) of edges represented as integers in the following format:

```
node1,node2
3213741,23521361
3213741,6532710
3213741,12340611
3213741,6457392
3213741,9682135
6567133,12956771
6567133,23860123
```

`node1` is where the edge starts and `node2` is where the edge ends. The edges are grouped by `node1` (can be grouped by `node2`).

I need to generate 2-step neighbors for all nodes. That is in the following format:

```
node1,node2,node3
3213741,6532710,5347128
```

My idea is to make a copy of the edges and sort them by node2,so there are two tables `t1.node1,t1.node2` and `t2.node1,t2.node2`, then somehow join these two tables when `t1.node1 == t2.node1` and `t1.node1 != t2.node2`. But this looks too slow. Is there any better algorithms or any algorithms that can utilize the fact that the data is grouped by `node1`? I prefer Numpy. Thank you.

Comment: It would be fairly easy in SQL. Since you have it in csv already you could import into a relational database and run a query against it.

Comment: Not helping with the actual question, but you might wanna have a look at [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) for saving your data. That can save a lot of space and speed up the loading/saving substantially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code implementing the sparse matrix approach proposed by [obachtos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528453/obachtos) and using [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) to run in parallel on a single node:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask
import time
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

np.random.seed(1)

# Fabricate some data
elem = int(1e7)
rng = int(1e5)
gr = np.random.randint(0, rng, elem * 2, np.uint32)
gr = gr.reshape((elem, 2))
gr = gr[np.argwhere(gr[:, 0] != gr[:, 1])]
gr = gr.reshape(-1, 2)
grdf = pd.DataFrame(data=gr)
gr = grdf.drop_duplicates().values

def coord2adjacency(coords, shp, order, chunksize):
    grsp = coo_matrix((np.ones(gr.shape[0]), (gr[:, 0], gr[:, 1])),
                      shape=(shp, shp))
    grcsr = grsp.tocsr()
    adj = grcsr**order
    return adj

adjspdel = dask.delayed(coord2adjacency,
                        pure=True, nout=1, traverse=False)(gr, shp=rng,
                                                           order=2,
                                                           chunksize=5000)
print('Computing an adjacency matrix of order {ordr} from {n} coordinates.'\
      .format(ordr=2, n=gr.shape[0]))
t0 = time.time()
adjsp = adjspdel.compute()
print('Execution time: {tm} minutes.'.format(tm=(time.time() - t0) / 60))
```

On my 4-core/8 GB PC, the execution time was 4.1 minutes. The OP's problem is a few orders of magnitude larger still. The [dask distributed](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) package should permit code similar to this to run on a cluster large enough for the task.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how large your memory is you could create an adjacency matrix as a `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` (i.e. a matrix that has ones whenever two nodes are connected and zeros elsewhere), convert that to another type of sparse matrix and then take the square. This matrix has entries exactly where second order connections exist. The value of the entry even tells you how many paths exist between the nodes with length two.